# Trying to compile contract but getting "ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/IERC1155.sol" not found: File not found."

Tags: ethereum, solidity, brownie

I am trying to compile a contract so that I can start the brownie console but I keep getting the error for the contracts I am trying to import.

```
ParserError: Source "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/IERC1155.sol" not found: File not found.
 
--> contracts/DutchAuction.sol:3:1:

  |
3 | import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC1155/IERC1155.sol";
  | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^`
```

How would I go about fixing this? Much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When [importing packages, per the brownie docs](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/package-manager.html?highlight=import#importing-sources-from-a-package) you first have to install the packages. You can install them from:

- [Install from github](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/package-manager.html?highlight=import#installing-from-github)
- [Install from ethpm](https://eth-brownie.readthedocs.io/en/stable/package-manager.html?highlight=import#installing-from-ethpm)

One of the most common ways is just installing directly from github releases. To do this, you have to update your `brownie-config.yaml` (or make this file it if you haven't already)

You then have to add the github repo as a dependency with the structure:

```
REPO_OWNER/REPO_NAME@RELEASE_VERSION
```

And then add it to remappings if you want to use the `@` syntax, like so:

```yaml
dependencies:
  - OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.3.2
compiler:
  solc:
    remappings:
      - '@openzeppelin=OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts@4.3.2'
```

This example should work for this specific use case if you pop it into your `brownie-config.yaml`

Comment: Thanks Patrick, I can continue on my project now. Greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same issue for days. I realized my mistake: the config file was named `brownie_config.yaml` (*with underscore*) instead of `brownie-config.yaml` (*with dash*)